# High reliability imply difference?

Tags: statistical-significance, reliability

Suppose a test has scores between $0$ and $50$. Alice scores a $34$ and Bob scores a $42$. Does a high Cronbach's $\alpha$ imply that the Alice and Bob's scores are statistically  significantly different? Intuitively if a test has a high $\alpha$ then it is internally consistent. Thus the difference should be significant?

Note that $\alpha = 0.91$.

Comment: Do you know the exact value of alpha?

Comment: @gung yes I do. $\alpha = 0.91$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume here your framework is Classical Test Theory, not Item Response Theory. Under CTT, the standard error of measurement (SEM) is:

$\sigma_e=\sigma_x \sqrt{1-\rho_x}$

$\rho_x$ is your reliability coefficient, $\sigma_x$ is the standard deviation of your scores. Input your $\alpha$ into that equation, and get your SEM, then use that to create confidence intervals for your point estimates of scores.

A big limitation to the CTT approach is that the SEM is assumed to be constant for everyone. Under IRT, standard errors change depending on the scores (specifically, where they fall in the information curves). This, in my view and in the view of statisticians way smarter than I, is preferable as the amount of information (inverse of error) is different depending on the responses.